# React native deep linking routing not working

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using dynamic links for deep linking.

```
const linking = {
  prefixes: [
    www.example.com
  ],
  config: {
    screens: {
    Chat: {
               path: ":id",
               parse: {
                         id: (id) => `${id}`,
                      },
           },
    Profile: 'user',
  },
  },
};

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking} fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Chat" component={ChatScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

`www.example.com/user` always route to the `ChatScreen` screen. I want to route in `ProfileScreen`. How to handle config file in linking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your `config`  as

```
const config = {
  screens: {
    Profile: '/user',
    Chat:'/chat/:id'
  },
};
```

your `linking` should be

```
const linking = {
  prefixes: [
    'www.example.com',
  ],
  config,
};
```

By doing so, `www.example.com/user` will be routed to `ProfileScreen` component. `www.example.com/chat/:<some id>` will take you to `ChatScreen` with route param as `id`.

**Update**: It seems you are trying to go to `ChatScreen` by `www.example.com/<some id>` and also have `www.example.com/user` to load `ProfileScreen`. The problem is React navigation considers string `"user"` as param `id` and takes you to `ChatScreen` itself. That is the reason I added "chat" in the path of `ChatScreen`.

If you really want to use `www.example.com/<some id>` to load `ChatScreen`, you can use `getStateFromPath` and write your own logic to differentiate between ids and path names. To do that, your `linking` will be

```
   const linking = {
          prefixes: [
            'www.example.com',
          ],
          config,
         getStateFromPath: (path, options) => {
            if (path ==='/user') {
             return {routes: [{ name: 'Profile' }],   
       } ;
            } else {
            return {routes: [{ name: 'Chat',params:{id:getIdFromPath(path)} }],   
       } ;
            }
          },
        };
```

here `checkIfValidPath` is for checking whether the url path is an actual `id` or "user". `getIdFromPath` is to extract id from the url. I havent tested this, but this should work.

```
const checkIfValidPath=(path)=>{
return path !=='www.example.com/user';
}
const getIdFromPath =(path)=>{
return path.slice(1, path.length);

}
```

Comment: my URLs are  www.example.com/id and  www.example.com/user. i can't change.

Comment: @Shivam I have made changes to answer, try it and let me know.

Comment: @Shivam what did you not understand.

Comment: @Shivam `checkIfValidPath` should return true if the `path` is not equal to `www.example.com/user` .  And `getIdFromPath` should just extract `id` from `www.example.com/:<some id>` and return it.

Comment: @Shivam I have added everything you need, it should work, check and let me know.

Comment: to customise linking behaviour in React Navigation, we can use getStateFromPath, you can learn more from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container#linkinggetstatefrompath

Comment: @Shivam try the code and report back please

Comment: in `checkIfValidPath` , have you changed `www.example.com` to your url, and also check if the `path` contains domain name or is it just the path?

Comment: if it just the path, change the return statement in `checkIfvalidPath` to `return path !=='/user';`

Comment: @Shivam I made changes in getStateFromPath , please try it. Basically, we are trying to load Profile screen if path is '/user' if not to Chats screen. Console log the value of path in the function to see, what we are missing.

Comment: `import {getStateFromPath} from '@react-navigation/native';` for clearing reference error

Comment: @Shivam Did you get it??

Comment: @shivam can you post ur getStateFromPath function

Comment: getStateFromPath: (path, options) => {
            if (path === '/user') {
                return {
                    routes: [{ name: 'Profile' }],
                };
            } else {
                return {
                    routes: [{
                        name: 'Chat', params: {
                            id: getIdFromPath(path)
                        }
                    }],
                };
            }
        },

Comment: const getIdFromPath = (path) => {
        return path.slice(1, path.length);
    }

Comment: adding / to path name worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
    const getIdFromPath = (path) => { return path.slice(1, path.length); } 
    const linking = {
      prefixes: [
        www.example.com
      ],
      config: {
        screens: {
           Chat: {
                   path: ":id",
                   parse: {
                             id: (id) => `${id}`,
                          },
               },
          Profile: 'user',
        },
      },
        getStateFromPath: (path, options) => { 
           if (path === '/user') { 
               return { routes: [{ name: 'Profile' }], }; 
           } 
          else { 
               return { routes: [{ name: 'Chat', params: { id: getIdFromPath(path) } }], }; 
          } 
        }
    };
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer linking={linking} fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>
          <Stack.Screen name="Chat" component={ChatScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
```